# If $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, \ a^n - 1 \mid b^n - 1$ therefore $\exists p \in \mathbb{N}^*,\ b=a^p$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

> Let $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2 \le a \le b$. Suppose $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, \ a^n - 1 \mid b^n - 1$, show that $\exists p \in \mathbb{N}^*,\ b=a^p$.

I saw a solution using calculus (sequences and limits), but I'm looking for an arithmetical one (using classic arithmetic results such as Bézout's identity, Euclid's lemma, Fermat's little theorem, ...).

Comment: Since it is not clear what do you mean by calculus or arithmetic if would help if you include the "calculus" solution.

Comment: @JCAA The "calculus" solution is quite long to write (it's in $\textit{Oraux X-ENS : Algèbre 1}$) but the main idea is: we let $u_n = \frac{b^n - 1}{a^n - 1} \sim_{n \infty} \frac{b^n}{a^n}$, let $v_n = a u_{n+1} - b u_n$, if $a < b < a^2$ we can show that $v_n \to_{n \infty} 0$ but $(v_n)$ is a non-zero sequence of integers (proof by contradiction).

Comment: @Michelle What about the case when $a^2<b<a^3$?

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Let $w_n = a^2 v_{n+1} - b v_n$ by computing an equivalent you get the same contradiction as with $(v_n)$.

Comment: @Michelle The problem is indeed a lovely one, and I would dare say one shouldn't expect a purely algebraic solution. The reason I believe such a solution can't exist is that if this were true (i.e. if a purely algebraic reasoning sufficed to prove the result) we would also expect the analogous result to hold in arbitrary PIDs or at least UFDs...and who could tell whether this is the case or not? Even if one were to consider the analogous result stated for one indeterminate polynomials with coefficients in a given commutative field, *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @Michelle *(cont)* the proof would still rely on aspects of relative domination, given by the respective degrees of the rational functions involved. In other words, the reasoning which you indicate -- essentially based on asymptotic expansions and comparisons -- seems to be very natural and intrinsic to the context of the suggested problem. To conclude my lengthy comment, by algebraic means you could infer that any prime divisor of $b$ must also divide $a$, but that is far from making any substantial progress.